# Turning a singly linked list into a list of integers recursively

Tags: python, list, recursion, singly-linked-list

I am trying to turn a singly linked list into a list of integers in a recursive manner. I have attempted to write a function but it doesn't work as I intend it to.
The function should take in a list like `Node(1, Node(2, None))` and should return a list of integers like `[1, 2]`.
I have attempted to write the function below but the output I'm getting is `[1]`. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong as I'm very new to recursion.

```
def linked(items: Optional[Cell]) -> List[int]:
    if items is None:
        return None
    elif items.next is not None:
        list_int = []
        list_int.append(items.data)
        linked(items.next)
        return list_int
```

Here is the class definition for Cell:

```
class Cell:
    data: int
    next: Optional[Cell]

    def __init__(self, data: int, next: Optional[Cell]):
        """Constructs a singly linked list."""
        self.data = data
        self.next = next
```

***edited to be more focused and clear

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  There are many examples on Stack Overflow and elsewhere on line that show you how to accumulate results in a recursive process.  We expect you to search out and use those resources before posting here.

Comment: First of all, don't call your function `list`, because then you no longer _see_ the built-in list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what node is supposed to be but I guess what you want to do is create a list of integers from nested lists of integers. If so, here's a code that I think works fine:

```py
def unpack_nested_lists(L):

    list_of_integers = []

    for element in L:

        if type(element) is list:
            list_of_integers += unpack_nested_lists(element)

        else:
            list_of_integers.append(element)

    return list_of_integers
```

I hope it will help you out,

Paul

Answer (score 0):

Attempting to fill in the code you didn't provide, is this roughly what you're trying to do:

```
class LinkedList():
    def __init__(self, data, link):
        self.data = data
        self.link = link

    def toList(self):
        if self.link is None:
            return [self.data]

        return [self.data] + self.link.toList()

example = LinkedList(1, LinkedList(7, LinkedList(7, LinkedList(6, None))))

print(example.toList())
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
[1, 7, 7, 6]
>
```